# How can I sequence this MySQL table correctly

Tags: mysql, sequencing

I've got a table containing a mixture of left and right shoes, some of which are waterproof.

I need to write a query to sort them alphabetically, but- when the name is the same- use the waterproof column ahead of left/right.

e.g.

```
+-------------------------+------------+------------+
| Shoe name               | Waterproof | Left/Right |
+-------------------------+------------+------------+
| boot                    |     0      |   left     |
| sandal                  |     0      |   left     |
| shoe                    |     1      |   left     |
| boot                    |     1      |   left     |
| boot                    |     0      |   right    |
| boot                    |     1      |   right    |
| sandal                  |     0      |   right    |
| shoe                    |     1      |   right    |
+-------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Should be sorted as such...

```
+-------------------------+------------+------------+
| Shoe name               | Waterproof | Left/Right |
+-------------------------+------------+------------+
| boot                    |     0      |   left     |
| boot                    |     0      |   right    |
| boot                    |     1      |   left     |
| boot                    |     1      |   right    |
| sandal                  |     0      |   left     |
| sandal                  |     0      |   right    |
| shoe                    |     1      |   left     |
| shoe                    |     1      |   right    |
+-------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Can it be done?

Comment: why is left and right not its own column?

Comment: It could be. Would it help?

Comment: you are storing an additional 7-8 characters verses a bit (1 or 0) representing the foot.

Comment: Ok I've changed it to its own column.

Comment: on another note, if it is a column, you could do something:
select * from footwear order by showname asc, shoe asc, waterproof asc;  which would give you your output

Comment: shoe.left = 0, shoe.right = 1... then asc will put in that order. :)

Comment: ORDER BY shoe_name,waterproof,lef_right DESC - or something like that. Also, take a look at FIELD()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But what if the sandals were not waterproof?*

On your modified data structure, the following should work:

```
SELECT `Shoe name`, `Waterproof`, `Left/Right`
 FROM shoe_table
  ORDER BY CONCAT( `Shoe name`, ', ', `Waterproof` ), `Left/Right`;
```

---

You can try:

```
select * from shoes order by 2, 1;
```

OR by column name:

```
select * from shoes order by Waterproof, `Shoe name`;
```

Comment: Hmm..Yes ok. It works for this example. But what if the sandals were not waterproof? In fact, I'll change it so they're not. It makes the point clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY ShoeName,Waterproof
```

Comment: That would not work. It would have non-waterproof left boot sequenced before waterproof left boot.

Answer (score 0):

This requires parsing the `shoes` column.  The easiest way is using `substring_index()`:

```
order by substring_index(ShoeName, '(', 1), Waterproof, ShowName
```